# Add all Quantity Value with the same ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sum

I want to get the sum of `Qty` Column with the same `ProductID`.

| Qty | ProductID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 |
| 1 | 1002 |
| 1 | 1002 |
| 1 | 1001 |
| 1 | 1001 |
| 1 | 1001 |

So far this is my query:

```
SELECT
Sales.Qty,
Sales.ProductID,
Products.ProductDesc,
Sales.Status FROM
dbo.Sales
INNER JOIN dbo.Products ON Sales.ProductID = Products.ProductID
```

Comment: Have you looked at the `SUM` function?

Comment: @Larnu yes sir but it gives me this " is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." and dont know how to fix it.

Comment: The error *is* telling you the problem there; you have a column that isn't aggregated and isn't in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Query with SUM with Group By](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41816846/sql-query-with-sum-with-group-by)

Comment: but i added it with the group by clause `SELECT
 Sum(Sales.Qty) as Sqty,
 Sales.ProductID,
 Products.ProductDesc,
 Sales.Status 
FROM
 dbo.Sales
 INNER JOIN dbo.Products ON Sales.ProductID = Products.ProductID 
 GROUP BY Sales.ProductID`

Comment: @sim123 assuming there are multiple sales (with their own status) per product, what are you expecting to happen here if you have 1 result row per product with the summed sales qty? Do you want to concatenate a list of all the statuses? DO you actually need sales status in the results (see the upvoted answer if not)

Comment: *"but i added it with the group by clause"* What about  `Products.ProductDesc` and `Sales.Status` @sim123 ? They are neither aggregated nor in the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `ProductID` uniquely identifies a product, you could group by the `ProductID` and `ProductName`:

```
SELECT     SUM(Sales.Qty),
           Sales.ProductID,
           Products.ProductDesc,
FROM       dbo.Sales
INNER JOIN dbo.Products ON Sales.ProductID = Products.ProductID 
GROUP BY   Sales.ProductID, Products.ProductDesc
```